# How to disable RTTI in C++ for MVSC compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, rtti

I want to disable RTTI in C++. I'm using MSVC compiler.
I set compiler flag `/GR-`. And example code to check:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _CPPRTTI
#error "RTTI enabled"
#endif

struct TestStructureName_123456 {

};

int main() {
  printf("%s\n", typeid(TestStructureName_123456).name());

  return 0;
}
```

`_CPPRTTI` defines if RTTI is enabled ([info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gr-enable-run-time-type-information?view=msvc-160)).
Preprocessor error doesn't occurs, it means that RTTI is disabled.
But typeid successfully returns name of the structure. Why?
And raw symbol name exists in binary symbols strings. How can I solve it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Side note: `https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid` says "The header <typeinfo> must be included before using typeid (if the header is not included, every use of the keyword typeid makes the program ill-formed.)"

Comment: If you remove the usage of `typeid()` and also add [`/Zi`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/z7-zi-zi-debug-information-format?view=msvc-160) when compiling. Does it still contain the symbol names?

Comment: The test is just not valid, the compiler has no trouble generating the name at compile-time.  You'd have to put it to the test with a polymorphic class (add a virtual function) and take the typeid of a reference or dereferenced pointer to an object of the class.  You'll get C4541 at compile time to warn you that it isn't going to work correctly.

Comment: @HansPassant, okay, but can I prevent the generation of type names? I'm also using `std::any`, it stores type, but I think that can work only using type hash without full symbol name.

Answer (score 0):

In your test you are using static type information with `typeid` call (that does not need rtti to resolve).

It is only for the case when a glvalue expression that identifies an object of a polymorphic type, that rtti will be used.

> If expression is a glvalue expression that identifies an object of a
> polymorphic type (that is, a class that declares or inherits at least
> one virtual function), the typeid expression evaluates the expression
> and then refers to the std::type_info object that represents the
> dynamic type of the expression. If the glvalue expression is obtained
> by applying the unary * operator to a pointer and the pointer is a
> null pointer value, an exception of type std::bad_typeid or a type
> derived from std::bad_typeid is thrown.

You should make a test that uses the **runtime** type information.

See also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64768421/how-to-disable-rtti-in-c-for-mvsc-compiler/64768866#comment114517082_64768421).